# Python sci-kit learn (metrics): difference between r2_score and explained_variance_score?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I noticed that that `r2_score` and `explained_variance_score` are both build-in `sklearn.metrics` methods for regression problems.

I was always under the impression that `r2_score` is the percent variance explained by the model.  How is it different from `explained_variance_score`?

When would you choose one over the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, look at this example:

```
In [123]:
#data
y_true = [3, -0.5, 2, 7]
y_pred = [2.5, 0.0, 2, 8]
print metrics.explained_variance_score(y_true, y_pred)
print metrics.r2_score(y_true, y_pred)
0.957173447537
0.948608137045
In [124]:
#what explained_variance_score really is
1-np.cov(np.array(y_true)-np.array(y_pred))/np.cov(y_true)
Out[124]:
0.95717344753747324
In [125]:
#what r^2 really is
1-((np.array(y_true)-np.array(y_pred))**2).sum()/(4*np.array(y_true).std()**2)
Out[125]:
0.94860813704496794
In [126]:
#Notice that the mean residue is not 0
(np.array(y_true)-np.array(y_pred)).mean()
Out[126]:
-0.25
In [127]:
#if the predicted values are different, such that the mean residue IS 0:
y_pred=[2.5, 0.0, 2, 7]
(np.array(y_true)-np.array(y_pred)).mean()
Out[127]:
0.0
In [128]:
#They become the same stuff
print metrics.explained_variance_score(y_true, y_pred)
print metrics.r2_score(y_true, y_pred)
0.982869379015
0.982869379015
```

So, when the mean residue is 0, they are the same. Which one to choose dependents on your needs, that is, is the mean residue **suppose** to be 0?

Comment: why `metrics.r2_score(y_true, y_pred)` not equals to `metrics.r2_score(y_pred, y_true)`

Comment: I guess, you could have used `np.var` instead of `np.cov`. Confused me a bit. You are not really calculating covariance, but a variance. Also taking standard deviation and then squaring simply mean taking variance: `4*np.array(y_true).std()**2  =  4*np.var(y_true)  =  29.1875`

Answer (score 38):

Most of the answers I found (including here) emphasize on the difference between [R<sup>2</sup>](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html#sklearn.metrics.r2_score) and [Explained Variance Score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.explained_variance_score.html#sklearn.metrics.explained_variance_score), that is: **The Mean Residue** (i.e. The Mean of Error).

However, there is an important question left behind, that is: Why on earth I need to consider The Mean of Error?

---

**Refresher:**

R<sup>2</sup>: is the *Coefficient of Determination* which measures the amount of variation explained by the (least-squares) Linear Regression.

You can look at it from a different angle for the purpose of evaluating the *predicted values of `y`* like this:

**Variance**<sub>actual_y</sub> × **R<sup>2</sup>**<sub>actual_y</sub> = **Variance**<sub>predicted_y</sub>

So intuitively, the more R<sup>2</sup> is closer to `1`, the more actual_y and predicted_y will have *same* variance (*i.e. same spread*)

---

As previously mentioned, the main difference is the **Mean of Error**; and if we look at the formulas, we find that's true:

```
R2 = 1 - [(Sum of Squared Residuals / n) / Variancey_actual]

Explained Variance Score = 1 - [Variance(Ypredicted - Yactual) / Variancey_actual]
```

in which:

```
Variance(Ypredicted - Yactual) = (Sum of Squared Residuals - Mean Error) / n
```

So, obviously the only difference is that we are subtracting the **Mean Error** from the first formula! ... **But Why?**

---

When we compare the **R<sup>2</sup> Score** with the **Explained Variance Score**, we are basically checking the **Mean Error**; so if R<sup>2</sup> = Explained Variance Score, that means: The Mean Error = **Zero**!

The Mean Error reflects the tendency of our estimator, that is: the **Biased v.s Unbiased Estimation**.

---

### In Summary:

If you want to have unbiased estimator so our model is not underestimating or overestimating, you may consider taking **Mean of Error** into account.

Comment: so you recommend using the explained_variance score over r2 score ?

Comment: Isn't it:  V( Yactual - Ypredicted) for Explained Variance Score

Comment: @msarafzadeh look at the general variance formula, you'll find that it doesn't matter either ways.

Comment: is it because both are independent of each other so V(Yi-Yp) == V(Yi)+V(Yp) ?

Comment: @msarafzadeh yes Var(X+Z) = Var(X)+Var(Z) and also Var(aZ) = a^2 * Var(Z), where 'a' is a constant then Var(Y-Yp)=Var(-1(Yp-Y))=(-1)^2 * Var(Yp-Y) = Var(Yp-Y).

Comment: I don't think `Variance(Ypredicted - Yactual) = (Sum of Squared Residuals - Mean Error) / n` is correct. It should be `sum((Ypredicted - Yestimated - Mean Error)**2) / N`. Check the source code:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13af77c76e150b753485c662b7c52a41a2/sklearn/metrics/_regression.py#L557

Comment: They are the same thing: (1) model = LinearRegression(); model.score(X=x_column_name, y=y_column_name]]) and (2) metrics.explained_variance_score(y_column_name, y_predicted) will give exactly same output, i.e., same percentage number. Both are r^2 of linear regression model. Reference: R square formula: https://www.ncl.ac.uk/webtemplate/ask-assets/external/maths-resources/statistics/regression-and-correlation/coefficient-of-determination-r-squared.html